# Mac node webkit crash

Tags: mysql, node-webkit

I'm trying to make a NodeWK app and sometimes it works but most of the time it quit by itself throwing this log :

```
Process:         node-webkit Helper [19804]
Path:            /Users/USER/*/G4-supervisor.app/Contents/Frameworks/node-webkit Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/node-webkit Helper
Identifier:      com.intel.nw.helper
Version:         32.0.1700.107 (1700.107)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  node-webkit [19761]
Responsible:     node-webkit [19761]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-06-26 11:33:13.563 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  D2604DB0-20D2-EA4C-8A6E-B510AA4268E8

Sleep/Wake UUID: E182229F-8926-4545-BD57-42369F3452BC

Crashed Thread:  0  CrRendererMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Users/USER/*/G4-supervisor.app/Contents/Frameworks/node-webkit Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/node-webkit Helper
    VM_ALLOCATE            0000000000001000-000000000009f000 [  632K] ---/--- SM=NUL  

Thread 0 Crashed:: CrRendererMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x91b76710 strlen + 16
1   node-webkit Framework           0x002ee701 v8::String::NewFromOneByte(v8::Isolate*, unsigned char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int) + 241
2   node-webkit Framework           0x001c45db node::uv::ErrName(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) + 203
3   node-webkit Framework           0x002ff5e9 0xa3000 + 2475497
4   node-webkit Framework           0x0031aa2b 0xa3000 + 2587179
5   ???                             0x5a60c296 0 + 1516290710
6   ???                             0x3f1fa81a 0 + 1059039258
7   ???                             0x6009b2a6 0 + 1611248294
8   ???                             0x5a63f7d9 0 + 1516500953
9   ???                             0x5a6230ea 0 + 1516384490
10  node-webkit Framework           0x0035c317 0xa3000 + 2855703
11  node-webkit Framework           0x0035bee2 0xa3000 + 2854626
12  node-webkit Framework           0x002ebb6c v8::Function::Call(v8::Handle<v8::Value>, int, v8::Handle<v8::Value>*) + 268
13  node-webkit Framework           0x001da845 node::AsyncWrap::MakeCallback(v8::Handle<v8::Function>, int, v8::Handle<v8::Value>*) + 213
14  node-webkit Framework           0x001c3f71 node::UDPWrap::OnSend(uv_udp_send_s*, int) + 209
15  node-webkit Framework           0x00754095 0xa3000 + 7016597
16  node-webkit Framework           0x00756e0c 0xa3000 + 7028236
17  node-webkit Framework           0x0074974c uv_run + 332
18  node-webkit Framework           0x0010682c 0xa3000 + 407596
19  node-webkit Framework           0x00105d2c 0xa3000 + 404780
20  node-webkit Framework           0x0014a132 0xa3000 + 684338
21  node-webkit Framework           0x00164b5e 0xa3000 + 793438
22  node-webkit Framework           0x00149b1a 0xa3000 + 682778
23  node-webkit Framework           0x02557178 0xa3000 + 38486392
24  node-webkit Framework           0x02c7cf92 0xa3000 + 45981586
25  node-webkit Framework           0x02c7dd23 0xa3000 + 45985059
26  node-webkit Framework           0x02c7cce0 0xa3000 + 45980896
27  node-webkit Framework           0x000a49b9 ContentMain + 41
28  com.intel.nw.helper             0x0009ff75 0x9f000 + 3957
```

I'm using a few things like `mysql` connections and `vue.js`. As I don't know from where it comes, I can provide informations if needed.

Comment: I'm having the same issues. Have you solved the problem? Which node webkit version are you using?

Comment: @red_alert I use `V32.0.1700.107` I finished my work on windows so I can't tell you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently playing around with this. It appears that node webkit crashes if you close the last window.

Solution: quit the app with **gui.Window.get().close();**

```
menu.items[0].submenu.append(new gui.MenuItem({
    label: 'Close',
    click: function () {
        gui.Window.get().close();
    }
}));
```